# How to unit test html content generated by a Rails mailer?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, capybara, actionmailer

I have come across a few tools that make it easier to test emails generated in a Rails app, but they are designed to be used in integration tests (i.e. [capybara-email](https://github.com/dockyard/capybara-email)). However, I am writing a unit test that works directly with the mailer.

I currently have a test for my mailer that looks something like this:

```
RSpec.describe DigestMailer do
  describe "#daily_digest" do
    let(:mail) { DigestMailer.daily_digest(user.id) }
    let(:user) { create(:user) }

    it "sends from the correct email" do
      expect(mail.from).to eql ["support@example.com"]
    end

    it "renders the subject" do
      expect(mail.subject).to eql "Your Daily Digest"
    end

    it "renders the receiver email" do
      expect(mail.to).to eql [user.email]
    end

    it "renders the number of new posts" do
      expect(mail.body.raw_source).to match "5 New Posts"
    end
  end
end
```

However, I want to be able to test the html content a little easier than simply using regular expressions.

What I would really like to be able to do is something like this:

```
within ".posts-section" do
  expect(html_body).to have_content "5 New Posts"
  expect(html_body).to have_link "View More"
  expect(find_link("View More").to link_to posts_url
end
```

I don't know if there is a way to use Capybara directly to achieve something like this. Maybe there are alternatives that can provide similar functionality?

Answer (score 4):

According to [this Thoughtbot article](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/use-capybara-on-any-html-fragment-or-page), you can convert a string to a `Capybara::Node::Simple` instance. This allows you to use capybara matchers against it.

I've created a helper method that uses this:

```
def email_html
  Capybara.string(mail.html_part.body.to_s)
end
```

Which I can then use as follows:

```
expect(email_html).to have_content "5 New Posts"
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but you should be able to include the Capybara Matchers into your mailer specs (like Capybara does for view specs by default) by adding

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Capybara::RSpecMatchers, :type => :mailer
end
```

and then in your test something like

```
expect(mail.html_part.body.to_s).to have_content('blah blah')
expect(mail.html_part.body.to_s).to have_link('View More', href: posts_url)
```

Note - this adds matchers, not finders, so you use the options to have_link rather than using find_link

Comment: Hmm...unfortunately, this does not work because `mail.html_part` does not respond to `has_content?`

Comment: ummm --- it shouldn't be calling has_content?  on it, unless html_part doesn't return a string -- I'll have to check -- updated to access the string that is the body of the html_part